# Creating a user, mapping to a database and assigning roles to that database using SQL scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

I've done this before but not through scripts. I've to create a new user in SQL server (SQL Authentication) and map the user to a database and assign the roles for the user to that database using SQL scripts.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can do this in SSMS and click the "Script" icon to generate a script to look at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE USER [Username] FOR LOGIN [Domain\Username]
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'DatabaseRole', N'Username'
```

Obviously changing Username, and Domain\Username and the database role to being the username that you wish to grant rights to and the level of access, such as 'db_datareader'

Answer (score 5):

The above solution works for me. However if the Username doesnt yet exist in that database as a USER, that username will not be fully mapped to the database role.

In this situation I first add the user:

```
USE databasename

CREATE USER [DOMAIN\svce_name] FOR LOGIN [DOMAIN\svce_name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Then I add the role:

```
USE databasename
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ssisoperator', N'DOMAIN\svce_name'
GO
```