# Give users permission to access table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that users can be given permission to access the database to select data from database as shown below. But doing this for each user in the user table would take ages.. is there any method i could do this for all users in the user table

I want to give all of them roles to allow them to read certain tables only.. any ideas how this can be done.. but i dont want to do one user at a time i want to do the whole user table

```
CREATE LOGIN sam
    WITH PASSWORD = '';
USE AdventureWorks;
CREATE USER sam FOR LOGIN sam;
GO
GRANT SELECT TO sam
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a database role, grant the select permissions to that role and then add all the users into that database role.

Here is a link to a tutorial that demonstrates the concept:

[Custom Database Roles](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10181/sql-server-custom-database-role.aspx)

Comment: how would i do this as i really havnt wroked with sql table much

Comment: Reference to create roles - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

Comment: This should be useful to attach new users to existing roles -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603155/creating-a-user-mapping-to-a-database-and-assigning-roles-to-that-database-usin

Comment: how would i add all of the users in the user table to the role because this only explains one user at a time.. can u please give me a example

Comment: as all in want them to do is read from a couple of tables in the database not all

Comment: @user2108195 - I have added a link to a brief tutorial that explains the concept.

Comment: but the like doesnt tell me how to do the all the user and their passwords at once

Comment: how would i connect as the new user

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look in [granting permissions](http://databases.about.com/od/security/a/accesscontrols_2.htm),  you can see using of the option

```
[ON <table>]
```

Comment: How would i allow them just to select the data if My Table is called users and to do the select u have to eneter a password

Comment: In this case I think that is useful to see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11045/grant-table-privileges-to-a-user-connecting-from-any-host

Comment: this link is a bit confuing as i am a novice at SQL