# Explain this SQL Script to create user and assign role

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create an SQL User: and came across this script:

```
CREATE USER [Username] FOR LOGIN [Domain\Username]
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'DatabaseRole', N'Username'
```

at this link:
[Creating a user, mapping to a database and assigning roles to that database using SQL scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603155/creating-a-user-mapping-to-a-database-and-assigning-roles-to-that-database-usin)

Can someone explain this script to me:

1. what is `[Domain\Username]?`
2. [Username] = The userName I want,
3. what is `sp_addrolemember`?
4. What is N'DatabaseRole',?
5. What shall I put as N'Username'? The username same as [Username]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: `[Domain\Username]` is for the windows `Active Directory`-user for that domain.

Example: Say you have an AD/Domain/Computer called `StackOverFlow`, that would be the `Domain`, and then your username is `Awan`, that makes it `StackOverFlow\Awan`

2: Correct, this is the username you want you just insert your username there (within the brackets)

Example `[Awan]`

3: `sp_addrolemember` is a function that adds the user with a specific role. (dbo and such)

4: `N'DatabaseRole'` is a numeric text where you write in what role your user is supposed to have. An example is `db_owner`, which makes the user able to create tables, delete tables, alter tables, and so on.

5: Exactly, you just put for example `N'Awan'` instead of `N'Username'`

Otherwise you can create a user from SSMS ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx )

Comment: Is this script that I mentioned above for Network users? like "sa"?

Comment: Your script is most likely aimed at domain-users (And `sa` (server administrators if I'm not mistaken)). But generally you can use this script with simple modification to fit your needs. But it is easier to create with SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: can you write an example for me of the script?

Comment: Are you on a network (Domain) or just a single server? In either case I'll need the domain-name (Not URL) or the name of the server. Note that this script does not set a password, it is aimed for users that can log on to the server.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using WINDOWS server you can only create user for users who have access on windows server.

1. SERVERNAME\USERNAME E.g. TEMP_SERVER\Ashutosh
2. Uknow this
3. This Sp is basically sets roles for a user.
   4&5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx

Below is a way to do it in GUI

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Answer (score 1):

1. `[Domain\Username]` is a format of windows authentication logon name; you use it to log on to things, one of them is SQL Server
2. `[Username] = The userName I want` - I hope so, it should exist on your domain, or if Domain is computer name, then it has to exist on your computer
3. `sp_addrolemember` is a stored procedure that assigns a role to your user; roles can be e.g. database level roles like `db_owner`, `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`...
4. Look at 3.
5. If I have user MyUser on MyComputer, I would put MyComputer\MyUser; If I have user MyUser on MyDomain, I would put MyDomain\MyUser